# Why is the AJAX call coming back with a status code 0

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm exploring AJAX form submission and I've run into a problem where my AJAX call is returning an error with little to no information as to why.

My SubmitForm method is as follows:

```
function SubmitForm(FormId,Container) 
{  
    var FormElement = document.getElementById(FormId);
    var TargetUrl = document.URL + "resource/form/" + FormId + ".php";
    var SubmitUrl = TargetUrl + "?action=submit";
    var SuccessUrl = TargetUrl + "?action=success";
    var ErrorUrl = TargetUrl + "?action=failure";
    var DataString = "";

    for( var i = 0; i < FormElement.length; i++ )
    {
        if( i > 0 )
            DataString += "&"

        DataString += FormElement.elements[i].name + "=" + FormElement[i].value;
    } 

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: SubmitUrl,  
      data: DataString,  
      success: function() { 
        RequestAjax(Container,SuccessUrl); 
      },
      error: function(object, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown + "|" + object.status + "|" + object.responseText);
          RequestAjax(Container,ErrorUrl);
      }
    });
    return false; 
}
```

Being submit from:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Login" onClick="javascript: SubmitForm('loginForm','userData');" />
```

And I am getting output something like this;

```
error||0|
```

I know that the URL that I'm trying to hit exists, and have used basically identical code in another instance to submit a form, but am encountering the truly indescript problem that you see above.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling `SubmitForm`?

Comment: Generally speaking, you do NOT need to do your own string generation for the form's data. you can just `serialize()` the form and jquery will take care of all that for you. With your method you risk producing broken strings if any of the field names/values contain HTML/form metacharacters.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I know that I'm passing the data down the way I intend as I've seen this work - I'm calling SubmitForm from the Submit button itself - I'll add the code.

Comment: Fully failed to return properly... Apologies. Solution determined.

Comment: That `javascript: ` in your code is not necessary and could be considered harmful. It is [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) to be used with `break` and `continue` statements, not something to tell the browser what language to expect. The browser already expects Javascript in an onclick attribute.

Comment: Thanks m8; I'll be sure to adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status of zero comes from when the page is running off the file protocol or the page is refreshed when the Ajax call is made. Without seeing how your method is being called, I am assuming you are doing it like

```
<form onsubmit="SubmitForm();" />
```

You are missing the return

```
<form onsubmit="return SubmitForm();" />
                ^^^^^^
```

or with the input's click

```
<input type="submit" onclick="SubmitForm();" />
```

which should be

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return SubmitForm();" />
                              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Much appreciated - you sparked the missing plug.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd try would be to UrlEncode your values:

```
var DataString = "";

for( var i = 0; i < FormElement.length; i++ )
{
    if( i > 0 )
        DataString += "&"

    DataString += FormElement.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURI(FormElement[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this happens when an Ajax process is aborted. This can happen if the page is unloaded, or if the server connection is reset for some reason.

btw: if you're using jQuery you're better off building your postdata string with `$(FormElement).serialize()`